# How can I bring back my world clock widget?

Tags: notifications, widgets

I love my world clock widget, but today I don't see it. How can I bring it back?

[image]

Comment: Did you reboot already?

Comment: @patrix yes, i did, not helped

Comment: Marked unclear: There is no Word clock widget, i can only find a *Words Only Clock Widget* and Apple's *World Clock Widget*

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences → Extensions and click on ‘Today’ to see the World Clock widget.  Make sure it has a check next to it.  When you go back to Notification Center, you should see the clock.

I've had problems where some of my widgets would disappear for no obvious reason.  I don't know why this happens but I always end up going back to Extensions to add them back.